# Define a max width for a group of columns in css-grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Is it possible to define a max width for a group of columns in css-grid?

I'm trying to use css-grid alongside bootstrap like flex-box markup to make fullwidth rows which align with the flex-box columns.

```css
.container__grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [view-start] minmax(1em, 1fr) repeat(12, 95px [col])/* Specify a max-width and center */
  [view-end];
}

.col-9--viewport-edge {
  grid-column: view-start/col 9;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516139008210-96e45dccd83b?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ac07676efc2ca5b11b548d8ae01301ba&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2200&q=80');
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.col--remaining {
  grid-column-end: col 12;
}
```

```html
<div class="container__grid">
  <div class="col-9--viewport-edge">
    <div class="col__inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col--remaining">
    <div class="col__inner">
      <p>col-3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's a sandbox [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXbxEo) in which the goal is to get the cat column starting at the viewport edge and finishing at column 9 so that both col-3's line up vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy, but maybe something this will work for you.

Instead of this:

```
.container__grid{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 
      [view-start] minmax(1em, 1fr) 
      repeat(12, 95px [col])
      [view-end];
  }

.col-9--viewport-edge{
   grid-column: view-start/col 9;
}

.col--remaining{
  grid-column-end: col 12;
}
```

Try this:

```
.container__grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 5%);
}

.col-9--viewport-edge {
   grid-column: 1 / 16;
}

.col--remaining {
   grid-column: 16 / 21;
 }
```

Not sure how you want to handle wider screen sizes.

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YRpQQy)

Comment: The above method works at smaller screens however the visual effect will be most impactful at larger screens and unfortunately doesn't line up vertically due to splitting the grid up in equal segments throughout.

Comment: Consider making the containers equal width throughout.